# how to pass a URL as a parameter in web.config in ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying to pass a URL from the web.config file to .ASPX file
I have tried creating a add key property in the web.config file 
and used that key in the .aspx page, but it does not take the URL.

```
<add key="ManageToken" value="http://www.w3schools.com/html/"/>

<tr>
<td align="right"><a href="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ManageToken").ToString"><font color="blue"> Manage Token</font></a>|
```

Any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the expression in a [code render block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
<a href="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ManageToken") %>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! I have tried adding the expression. The code compiles now but when I click on the link, it does not take me to the URL site, but moves to the root folder of the web directory. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It depends on what the value is of `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ManageToken")`

Comment: I am trying to pass a URL link.                                                                 <add key="ManageToken" value="http://www.w3schools.com/html/"/>

Comment: It did start with "http://", some how it did not get printed. <add key="ManageToken" value="http://www.w3schools.com/html/"/>                   But it still goes to the root directory.

Comment: If the element is rendered as `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">...</a>`, then it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue. I had to use the System Configuration namespace to use the URL parameter.

Mark, Thanks for all the input.